# Tomcat 8 memory consumption breakdown

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, out-of-memory, tomcat8

Tomcat : apache-tomcat-8.0.21 
Java : 1.8.0_91-b14

We have few wars deployed in the tomcat. `Heap` min and max are set to 1GB. And `MaxMetaspace` is set to 256MB.

From top and htop cmd, RES memory usage is 2244M .
Apart from heap and metaspace memory, the rest is about 964MB. 
2244M(RES mem) - 1024M(Heap) - 256M(Metaspace) = **964M**

**What does this 964MB memory comprise of?** How can I verify the same using jdk tools?
When we removed all applications in webapp and restarted, it was not even 1MB RES memory usage.

Screenshots:
Tomcat memory usage using Top unix cmd
[image: Tomcat memory usage using Top unix cmd]
metaspace usage from gc log
[image: metaspace usage from gc log]

jvm flags
[image: jvm flags]

Tomcat memory usage using Htop unix cmd
[image: Tomcat memory usage using Htop unix cmd]

---

**Using Native memory tracking**(taken at different time from above data)
Following is the output of `native memory` cmd. Addition of all the `committed` values are not summing up to the RAM usage(1825M or 1.8gb).

```
1693M  = Sum of all groups committed values(only committed on the first line of each group )

[root@iyc krishna]# sudo -u tomcat /opt/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/jcmd 22239 VM.native_memory summary
22239:

Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=2894609KB, committed=1723517KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=1048576KB, committed=1048576KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=1048576KB, committed=1048576KB) 

-                     Class (reserved=1258404KB, committed=239444KB)
                            (classes #41586)
                            (malloc=5028KB #81169) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1253376KB, committed=234416KB) 

-                    Thread (reserved=184932KB, committed=184932KB)
                            (thread #176)
                            (stack: reserved=179900KB, committed=179900KB)
                            (malloc=580KB #885) 
                            (arena=4453KB #352)

-                      Code (reserved=270879KB, committed=120795KB)
                            (malloc=21279KB #27527) 
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=99516KB)     

-                    GC (reserved=81676KB, committed=81676KB)
                            (malloc=9996KB #52352) 
                            (mmap: reserved=71680KB, committed=71680KB) 

-                  Compiler (reserved=4901KB, committed=4901KB)
                            (malloc=312KB #745) 
                            (arena=4589KB #9)

-                  Internal (reserved=12462KB, committed=12462KB)
                            (malloc=12430KB #55846) 
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB) 

-                    Symbol (reserved=19876KB, committed=19876KB)
                            (malloc=16192KB #176321) 
                            (arena=3684KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=6222KB, committed=6222KB)
                            (malloc=33KB #393) 
                            (tracking overhead=6189KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=4631KB, committed=4631KB)
                            (malloc=4631KB) 

-                   Unknown (reserved=2048KB, committed=0KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=2048KB, committed=0KB)
```

Top cmd results:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                              
22239 tomcat    20   0 4290m 1.8g  18m S 103.8 23.1  12:38.92 java
```

RES Memory value using htop: 1825M

why are the values not adding up to the value shown by Top cmd? Or am I calculating not properly?